# Is my conception of limit correct?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, definite-integrals, definition

$(1)$ Can I define the derivative
$\left(  \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}   \right)$ as a value which can never be reached when $\Delta x$ approaches zero but every value smaller (or greater in other cases) to it can be reached when $\Delta x$ approaches zero.

$(2) $Similarly can I define the definite integral
$\displaystyle \left( \int^b_a y\ dx     \right)$
as the value of Reimann sum (in which we take the smallest value of function on the interval $\Delta x$) which can never be reached when $\Delta x$ approaches zero but every value smaller to it can be reached when $\Delta x$ approaches zero.

Comment: Be sure not to confuse $\Delta x$ and $x$. The definition of a derivative is $\lim_\limits{\Delta x\to 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.

Comment: Sorry......mistyping

Comment: No. Consider the example where $y=1$ for all values of $x$. Then $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = 0$ for all choices of $\Delta x\neq 0$ and this is also the limit as $\Delta x\to 0$. So the limit in this case *is* reached (contradicting your claim "can never be reached") and furthermore *no* value smaller or greater than the limit is ever reached (contradicting your claim "every value smaller or greater to it can be reached").

Comment: @Christoph: Thanks.... I see.... So constant functions do not fit here. Any other flaws?

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider the example where $y=1$ for all values of $x$. Then $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = 0$ for all choices of $\Delta x\neq 0$ and this is also the limit as $\Delta x\to 0$. So the limit in this case *is* reached (contradicting your claim "can never be reached") and furthermore *no* value smaller or greater than the limit is ever reached (contradicting your claim "every value smaller or greater to it can be reached").

The right description is that $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = L$ means that for any choice of a small $\varepsilon>0$ the values of $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ are inside the range $(L-\varepsilon, L+\varepsilon)$ as long as $\Delta x$ is close enough to $0$. More precisely, for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that when $-\delta < \Delta x < \delta$, then $L-\varepsilon < \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} < L+\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

No. Both are false. The value might be reached (trivial example for the derivative: a linear function). And it is also false that "every" value ( in what range?) is attained, as the same example shows.

Your assertion is ( more or less) right if applied to the values of the variable , instead of to the function.

Comment: I have edited... Please have a look at it